# Tails OS hangs at bootstrap

Tags: installation, operating-system

I tried all that I can... Ok, all starts that I wants to install Tails OS 3.12 on my usb. I downloaded *.img file from the official website. I tried several programs (Universal Usb Installer, etcher, rufus), but when I change priority in BIOS and reboot computer starts on a start window with changing keyboard and language and then, when I click on "Start Tails" it starts glitching in left top corner, it freezes and doesen't do anything. I waited a half hour but it didn't work, then I tried to download an *.iso file from non-official site and got the same result.

All information that I can say: computer: Acer Nitro 5, OS: Windows 10 x64, Security boot: disabled, Usb device not in list of problem devices: USB Kingston DT50, Tried with: (official)*.img Tails amd64 3.12 and with (non-official)*.iso Tails 3.12 amd64, tried with this programs: Usb Universal Installer, rufus, etcher.

Please help.

Comment: The site has a long page of known issues, about graphic cards and other hardware.  Have you read it all? https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/index.en.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem, I have computer with two videoadapters (one intel and one nVideo), in the first screen when I must choose simple or troubleshooting mode, I must push TAB and appeares a boot menu, I eter Space (it's important), and input `xorg-driver=intel` and press Enter, it's started to loading system and it works!